# Ayuda con esta pagina en php

Tags: php, html, mysql

Hice una pagina web en php. Pero quiero agregarle algunas cosas como input y type en cada columna para buscar en cada tabla el campo correspondiente
La tabla correspondiente en mysql

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `coffee` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `price` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `roast` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `review` text,
  `ide` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;

--
-- Gegevens worden uitgevoerd voor tabel `coffee`
--

INSERT INTO `coffee` (`id`, `name`, `type`, `price`, `roast`, `country`, `image`, `review`) VALUES
(1, 'Cafe au Lait', 'Classic', 2.25, 'Medium', 'France', 'Images/Coffee/Cafe-Au-Lait.jpg', 'A coffee beverage consisting strong or bold coffee (sometimes espresso) mixed with scalded milk in approximately a 1:1 ratio.'')'),
(2, 'Caffe Americano', 'Espresso', 3.25, 'Medium', 'Italy', 'Images/coffee/caffe_americano.jpg', 'Similar in strength and taste to American-style brewed coffee, there are subtle differences achieved by pulling a fresh shot of espresso for the beverage base.'),
(3, 'Peppermint White Chocolate Mocha', 'Espresso', 3.25, 'Medium', 'Italy', 'Images/coffee/white-chocolate-peppermint-mocha.jpg', 'Espresso with white chocolate and peppermint flavored syrups and steamed milk. Topped with sweetened whipped cream and dark chocolate curls.'),
(4, 'Galao', 'Latte', 4.2, 'Light', 'Portugal', 'Images/Coffee/galao_kaffee_portugal.jpg', 'Galao is a hot drink from Portugal made of espresso and foamed milk');
```

Contiene la base de datos de la tabla:

```
//Get coffeeEntity objects from the database and return them in an array.
    function GetCoffeeByType($type) {
        require ('Credentials.php');
        //Open connection and Select database.     
        mysql_connect($host, $user, $passwd) or die(mysql_error);
        mysql_select_db($database);

        $query = "SELECT * FROM coffee WHERE type LIKE '$type'";
        $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $coffeeArray = array();

        //Get data from database.
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $id = $row[0];
            $name = $row[1];
            $type = $row[2];
            $price = $row[3];
            $roast = $row[4];
            $country = $row[5];
            $image = $row[6];
            $review = $row[7];
            $ide = $row[8];

            //Create coffee objects and store them in an array.
            $coffee = new CoffeeEntity($id, $name, $type, $price, $roast, $country, $image, $review);
            array_push($coffeeArray, $coffee);
        }
        //Close connection and return result
        mysql_close();
        return $coffeeArray;
    }
```

Y aqui esta el php final que conecta:

```
<?php
$title = "Manage coffee objects";
include './Controller/CoffeeController.php';
$coffeeController = new CoffeeController();

$content = $coffeeController->CreateOverviewTable();

if(isset($_POST['types']))
{
    //Fill page with coffees of the selected type
    $coffeeTables = $coffeeController->CreateCoffeeTables($_POST['types']);
}
else 
{
    //Page is loaded for the first time, no type selected -> Fetch all types
    $coffeeTables = $coffeeController->CreateCoffeeTables('%');
}

if(isset($_GET["delete"]))
{
    $coffeeController->DeleteCoffee($_GET["delete"]);
}

include './Template.php';      
?>
```

Cualquier sugerencia es bien recibida. Lo que quiero es incluir un input y un type para buscar en cada columna de la tabla.

Comment: Hola @Omar. Es un poco difícil de ver qué problema estás teniendo. ¿O acaso estás pegando todo tu código esperando que alguien te lo solucione? Pensá en alguien que te quiera ayudar, quizás te conviene [edit] la pregunta para que sea más sencilla de entender, yendo al grano. Te puede ayudar leer [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

Con esta funcion tu generas la Tabla en HTML que vas a mostrar con los datos,`$coffeeController->CreateCoffeeTables` pues si es ahi incluyele los input o Type en el diseño...
El error que te da por la conexion a la base de datos mira este Link que explica por qué?
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: una pregunta el uso de funciones esta obsoleto, si hay lo tengo que agregar pero en mi caso lo defino desde el php :                            $coffeeTables = $coffeeController->CreateCoffeeTables($_POST['types']);

Comment: en mi caso obtengo este error: Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\CoffeeWebsite\Model\CoffeeModel.php on line 30 se refiere a que no debo hacerle la conexion de este modo?

Comment: que hace la funcion CreateCoffeeTables()???

Comment: @Omar Alami estas usando algun framework o solo son clases hechas por ti en php????

Comment: Es una pagina hecha en php. Aqui hay mas detalles sobre el ejemplo que estoy editando: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tPspjWX8GXw

Comment: @Omar Alami pon solo que tiene el codigo de CreateCoffeeTables() nada mas es solo para ubicar me...

Comment: las consultas y funciones en mysql estan desactualizadas aora utilizo pdo